# __classPrivateFieldGet(...).getEip3770Address is not a function

Tags: gnosis-safe

Getting the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: __classPrivateFieldGet(...).getEip3770Address is not a function" while trying to get safes owned by the ownerAddress using the api-kit. Here is my code :

```
const getAllSafes = async (address) => {
    const ethAdapter = {
      ethers,
      signerOrProvider: signer,
    };

    const safeService = new SafeApiKit({
      txServiceUrl: "https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global",
      ethAdapter,
    });

    const safes = await safeService.getSafesByOwner(address);
    console.log(safes);
  };
```

Also tried using providers and other get functions in the safe api-kit

Answer (score 0):

`getEip3770Address` is a method defined in the interface of the `EthAdapter` class: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/4d1c0e14630f951c2498e1d4dd521403af91d6e1/packages/safe-core-sdk-types/src/ethereumLibs/EthAdapter.ts#L38

I would say your `ethAdapter` instance is not correctly instantiated. What version of `ethers` are you using and how is you `signer` initialized?